# Post hoc analysis following clmm (ordinal) with nested effects

Tags: r, mixed-model, ordered-logit, lsmeans

I have conducted an experiment to investigate whether a painful stimulus affects the time taken to feed in snakes. I have three treatment groups: AO (anaesthetic only), CS (chemical stimulus) and SS (surgical stimulus). I fed the animals once per week for 4 weeks and timed how long it would take for them to accept the meal. This time was then assigned a score (1-4) based on the proximity to "normal" feeding (determined before the experiment started). To analyse the data, I used the `ordinal` package in `R` to conduct a `clmm` including the individual (Subject) as a random effect.

This is the data (scorescat):
`data.frame':   70 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Subject  : Factor w/ 18 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Week     : Ord.factor w/ 4 levels "W0"<"W1"<"W2"<..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Treatment: Factor w/ 3 levels "AO","CS","SS": 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ Score    : Ord.factor w/ 4 levels "1"<"2"<"3"<"4": 1 2 1 2 1 2 3 4 2 4 ...`

In the ordinal package I conducted the following analysis:

```
f1m<-clmm(Score~Week+Treatment+(1|Subject),data=scorescat,Hess=TRUE)
summary(f1m)
```

Which gave:

```
Cumulative Link Mixed Model fitted with the Laplace approximation
formula: Score ~ Week + Treatment + (1 | Subject)
data:    scorescat
link  threshold nobs logLik AIC    niter     max.grad cond.H 
logit flexible  70   -55.58 129.16 414(1245) 5.26e-06 8.8e+01

Random effects:
Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev.
Subject (Intercept) 1.668    1.292
Number of groups:  Subject 18

Coefficients:
           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|) 
Week.L       -3.9725     1.0489  -3.787 0.000152 ***
Week.Q       -0.3672     0.7271  -0.505 0.613587
Week.C       -1.0308     0.6168  -1.671 0.094664
TreatmentCS   1.5996     1.1336   1.411 0.158216
TreatmentSS   3.5656     1.2245   2.912 0.003592 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Threshold coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error z value
1|2   2.5629     0.9328   2.747
2|3   3.9229     1.0778   3.640
3|4   6.4169     1.4457   4.439
```

In order to get the effects of `Week` and `Treatment` on the feeding score I used the `drop1` function:

`drop1(f1m,test="Chi")`

Which gave:

```
Single term deletions

Model:
Score ~ Week + Treatment + (1 | Subject)
          Df    AIC     LRT  Pr(>Chi)  
<none>       129.16 
Week       3 153.93 30.7724 9.492e-07 ***
Treatment  2 134.46  9.2973  0.009575 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I would now like to conduct a post-hoc analysis to investigate the significant effects of `Week` and `Treatment` and have thus far used `lsmeans` with Tukey adjustments:

```
summary(lsmeans(f1m,pairwise~Week,adjust="tukey",mode="linear.predictor",type="Score"))
summary(lsmeans(f1m,pairwise~Treatment,adjust="tukey",mode="linear.predictor",type="Score"))
```

What I am concerned about is that the analysis does not take into account the repeated measures (ie. that the individuals in each treatment group were measured on each of the four weeks), any advice on defining this in my code or a better method of analysing this data?

I'm new to this site and relatively new to working with `R` so apologies if the answer is simple or the question is not formatted correctly. Thanks in advance for any input anyone may have.

Comment: Why do you think the repeated measures are not being taken into account? The model specifies a variance component for subjects and that information is included in the covariance matrix that lsmeans recovers from the model. It uses that information in the post hoc analysis. So the repeated measures actually are being taken into account.

Comment: Thank you @rvl that's something I completely missed when I was considering this problem. As I said, I'm new to working with this kind of data so I posted the question mainly to ensure I was conducting the right tests for this kind of data and that the Tukey's post-hoc was appropriate following a clmm. Thanks again for the response.